# Mocking the context object in MR unit

Tags: hadoop, hbase, mrunit

I'm new to Hadoop and this is my first mapper program, which I'm unit testing through MR unit.

I'm passing the parameter(year) which I set through the config object

```
    Configuration config =new Configuration()           
    config.set("Year", "2012");
    Job job=new Job(config ,"Yearly");
```

My Mapper:

```
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{   
  Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
  String Year= conf.get("Year");
}
```

In the MR unit tests I'm mocking the context class along with the key , value

```
@Test
public void testMapper() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
  context = mock(Mapper.Context.class);

  Configuration conf=mock(Configuration.class);
  when(conf.get("Year")).thenReturn("2012");
  when(context.getConfiguration()).thenReturn(conf);
  mapper.map(row, result, context);
}
```

However not able to get the value(Year) in the mapping, receiving null. Am I doing this correct or ,Is there a better way to test the mapping.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using MRUnit's `MapperDriver` to test this?

Comment: I used the MRUnit's MapDriver and with this there is no need to mock the configuration object, we can set conf with MapDriver.setConfiguration(conf). However I required to mock the key and value and run the test as mapDriver.withInputKey(key).withInputValue().withOutput()..runTest();   Thank you.

Comment: You lost me towards the end of your comment - can you update your question to what you current have, and list what is still causing you problems - thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should get the configuration from mapdriver in your test code, like this:

```
Configuration conf = mapdriver.getConfiguration();
conf.set("Year","2013");
```